# GCC inline assembly error: block assembly operand not recognized

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

I've got yet another error trying to compile with **Apple GCC 4.2.1** using the **-fasm-blocks** argument (which enables **Intel style** assembly syntax) inline assembly code which worked in **MSVC**: **block assembly operand not recognized**, **label 'LASM$TYPE' used but not defined**:

```
typedef struct _MyStruct
{
    int data;
    //...
}MyStruct;

void testAsm()
{
    MyStruct *pMyStruct = new MyStruct(); // Please not that I create an instance of MyStruct here only for the sake of simplicity

    _asm
    {
        mov edi, pMyStruct
        add edi, TYPE MyStruct // error: block assembly operand not recognized. label 'LASM$TYPE' used but not defined
        //...
    };

    delete pMyStruct;
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  I've never seen syntax like that in Visual C++ ...

Comment: Actually, it's the first time I am seeing it too and I wasn't able to find documentation, which would cover it...

Comment: I also encountered a variation of this problem - in another inline assembly code the offset keyword is used: "mov eax, offset fptr", where fptr is a function "void fptr(void* pData)"... This time GCC reports an error "Block assembly operand not recognized" :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TYPE` is an [MSVC-specific](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh0awwe%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) `asm` keyword. Here it just means `sizeof`. I tried to find some gcc asm-block documentation on the web, but I gave up after ten minutes. Try

```
add edi,sizeof(MyStruct)
```

and variants. I don't have an Apple, so I can't try it out for you.

**Updated** to answer question in comment: Try this:

```
add edi,__offsetof(MyStruct,MyMember)
```

If it doesn't work, see ["Using the GNU Compiler Collection"](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Offsetof.html#Offsetof) for documentation.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be working! May I also ask you to tell me how to deal with the offset keyword?

Comment: Man, I can't believe I missed that... Thanks a lot, Tony!